# Python/R Code for creating a schema as shown below?

Tags: python, r, visualization

I need to prepare a set of flowcharts that look like this:

[image: :]

The goal here is to show dataset splits for training models, where the different colors show different categorical variables in the y-parm.
What is important here is that the ratio be perfectly preserved (80:20 here).

Please help me with the code to do so (preferably R).
I tried using DiagrammeR, but I lack a coding background and was thus unable to set the bar widths accurately.

Edit: As asked, here's my (admittedly poor) code:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("digraph flowchart {
      
      node [shape=rectangle, height=0.75, color=grey]
      ds1[label='Dataset-1', width=5]
      ds1tr[label='Training Set-1', width=4]
      ds1ts[label='Test Set-1', width=1]
      
      ds1->ds1tr;
      ds1->ds1ts
      }")
```

I need help to-

1. Position each node properly
2. Fix the colors in the proper ratio (9:1/8:2)
3. Beautify the arrows/edges

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried? Stack Overflow may help you with code that you have already written, but people here won't write it for you. More generally, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might have some luck using alluvial plots https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html

Comment: @jjramsey Hi, I've added what I could. Will this suffice?

Comment: @doRemy That seems perfect for my use case! Will check it out.